# Kronecker's approach to unique factorisation in algebraic number theory: books and references

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I have done a short course (one semester) on algebraic number theory at beginning graduate level, in which the Dedekind theory of ideals features prominently. However I have since discovered that there was an alternative approach put forward by Kronecker featuring 'divisors' which seems not to be used.

My question is, is there a good book for beginners or other reference that I could use to find out more about this? All the textbooks on algebraic number theory I have seen use ideals, certainly in my college library. Thank you

Comment: Here is already an answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26549/is-there-much-difference-between-kroneckers-and-dedekinds-methods-in-algebraic.